# How finally localize PhoneGap/Cordova app name on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm developing an internationalized version (english, french, spanish and german) of my PhoneGap app on iOs with PhoneGap Build.

### PROBLEM :

I would like to localize/internationalize the app name.

**I tried several solutions :**

- i18n : **not working** 
  http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/internationalization-of-app-names/
- Cordova localization plugin : **localize all the strings but not the app name**. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/
- Third party cordova-plugin-localization-strings (kelvinhokk) : **not working**
- Edit config.xml like cordova-plugin-pgb-ios-localize-app-name : **not working**

### QUESTION :

How to localize a PhoneGap app name on iOs build with Phonegap build ?

Comment: hi Pierre, i am the author of the plugin cordova-plugin-localization-strings, and the plugin should be working, perhaps you can issue a bug report so that i can help look into your problem?

Comment: @maskie Does it also change / localize the app's name on home screen?